# Gridview (collection view source) does not get the source from a awaitable function which calls an API in C# UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

here is the code for my CollectionViewSource

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Name="GridviewCVS"  IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

And code behind for the same is

```
  ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> list = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();
       list = await getMenuGrouped();


            GridviewCVS.Source = list;
```

when i run this without await and synchronously i get the values in my gridview, but when i try to run it asynchrounously and get the data from HTTPClient it doesnt show any values, added breakpoints, it shows data in that but doesnt show it in gridview.

```
     public async static Task<ObservableCollection<MenuModel>> GetMenu()
    {
        ObservableCollection<MenuModel> _menu = new ObservableCollection<MenuModel>();
        MenuVM viewModel = new MenuVM();

        List<MenuModel> AllMenuItems = await viewModel.GetAllMenuItems();

        foreach (var item in AllMenuItems)
        {
            _menu.Add(item);
        }

        return _menu;


    }
    public async static Task<ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>> getMenuGrouped()
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();

        ObservableCollection<MenuModel> _menu = new ObservableCollection<MenuModel>();
        _menu = await GetMenu();

        var query = from item in _menu
                    group item by item.CategoryName into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };

        foreach (var g in query)
        {
            GroupInfoList info = new GroupInfoList();
            info.Key = g.GroupName;
            foreach (var item in g.Items)
            {
                info.Add(item);
            }
            groups.Add(info);
        }

        return groups;
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the method *getMenuGrouped*

Comment: Added the code for getMenuGrouped

Comment: You mean when you run `getMenuGrouped` without await and  synchronously and everything works fine? I made a demo, but failed reproducing this problem. Could you post your XAML codes? Or maybe share a basic demo through online repo also helps.

Comment: Basically i found out a solution where the collectionviewsource was not populating the elements when you do the call asynchronous, i tried creating the collectionview source from c# and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I tried other way in trying to attach the data, the CollectionViewSource was in the xaml and the items were coming properly but not getting assigned to the view so tried the below and removed the binding from the UI.

```
            CollectionViewSource vs = new CollectionViewSource();
            vs.IsSourceGrouped = true;

            vs.Source = staticData.GridViewData;

            MenuGridView.ItemsSource = vs.View;
```

Basically did set the collection view source from c# code instead of binding, but still want to know why the above didnt work.